# Missing Visual Studio features when running in 64-bit mode

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

Can someone tell me why I don't have all of the dev studio windows available to me when I develop on a 64-bit platform?  I upgraded my dev desktop box to server 2003 x64 to match our deployment platform.  Since then (I'm using VS2005) I've noticed that several windows aren't available.  I can't view Processes (which is the most annoying) so I don't know which processes I'm attached to.  I can attach to a process fine, but it won't show me what is already running under the debugger.  There are others, but that's the one that sticks out in my mind at the moment.

My question is where are these limitations of developing under 64 bit documented (assuming they are)?  (Of course, I also get the "Edit/Continue" warning dialog all the time telling me that doesn't work in 64-bit)

Also, is VS2008 any better under 64 bit?

Follow-up:  Apparently my question is a little bit vague.  I'm developing a 64-bit app on a 64-bit development environment.  "Recompile it in x86" doesn't solve my problems.

Follow-up #2:  I'm giving it one more shot.  I WANT TO DEBUG A 64 BIT PROGRAM ON A 64 BIT ENVIRONMENT AND I DON'T HAVE ALL OF THE VISUAL STUDIO FEATURES SHOWING UP.  HOW DO I GET THEM?

Follow-up #3: I just installed XP 64 (previously I was using Server 2003 64-bit) and those features all showed up again (Process window, etc).  Apparently the server version of windows doesn't provide all of the dev features.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You have a problem to solve??? Where in your question lol..

Answer (score 1):

"Edit/Continue" can work if you change the build setting to X86 :)

Here was the suggestion from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206894/change-to-64-bits-not-allowed-when-trying-to-edit-in-debug-why) about it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with NUNIT when debugging code. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208985/nunitexe-cannot-work-on-vista-64bits-if-x86-build) was to use the special program in the \bin\ folder Nunit-x86.exe for old code built in x86 and use the Nunit.exe for x64 built.